# Handling offset or limit from Query in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get a number of rows from my DB but I can't find the problem with my query, here's the code:

```
var top = offset + 5; // 5 is the offset or step of the next limit

connection.query("SELECT name FROM restaurants WHERE active = 1 LIMIT ?, ?",[offset, top], function(err, results) {
...
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'd try printing out the query to `console.log` and then running in MySQL.

I believe your syntax is incorrect. Instead of `SELECT (*)` you'll want to lose the parens and have `SELECT *` instead...

Comment: I'll edit question, changed that select just because I had many things in there. I'm not really requesting everything.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just not getting any results?

Comment: Error: `[Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: What MySQL driver are you using?